# PHP Pthreads. "Class Threaded not found"

Tags: php, pthreads

I'm beginner in multithread in PHP with pthreads. I try to run some demo code to understand basics. 
So, I've installed pthreads:

```
# php -m | grep pthreads
pthreads

# php -v
PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep 25 2015 08:01:30)
```

I want to run few threads that connect to DB and make query, but using one shared  mysqli object. I run this code:

```
<?php

class SQLWorker extends Worker {

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database, $port = 3306) {
        $this->hostname = $hostname;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* the static class scope acts as a kind of thread local storage for this class */
        self::$connection = new MySQLi
        ($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password, $this->port);
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return self::$connection;
    }

    protected $hostname;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $database;
    protected $port;

    protected static $connection;
}

class SQLTask extends Threaded {
    public function __construct($sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }

    public function run() {
        /* fetch static (thread local) connection */
        $link = $this->worker->getConnection();

        if ($link) {
            /* execute query, keep result in local scope */
            $result = $link->query($this->sql);

            /* build up results as normal array */
            while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }
        }

        /* store results in a fetchable form */
        $this->rows = $rows;
    }

    public function getResults() {
        return $this->rows;
    }
}

$pool = new Pool(4,
    SQLWorker::connection,
    ["localhost", "username", "password", "database"]);

$pool->submit(
    $task = new SQLTask("SELECT 1"));

$pool->shutdown();

/* you have your normal array of data here */
var_dump($task->getResults());
```

And get error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Threaded' not found in pThreads.php on line 31
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: The code above references 5 classes yet you only show 2 - one of the classes you do not show is the one mentioned in the error message - namely `Threaded` ~ where is this defined? Is this defined?

Comment: As I understard - Threaded and Worker classes are defined in pthreads extension  - earlier I tried to use construction like `class myThread extends Thread` and it worked.

Comment: Ok - Just took a look at the php online manual and you are correct, my apologies.

Comment: `# pecl info pthreads
About pecl.php.net/pthreads-0.0.44
==================================
Release Type          PECL-style PHP extension (source code)
Name                  pthreads
Channel               pecl.php.net
Summary               Threading API
Description           A compatible Threading API for PHP5.3+
Release Date          2013-04-30 07:28:42
Release Version       0.0.44 (beta)
API Version           0.0.44 (beta)
package.xml version   2.0
Last Modified         2015-09-25 10:01
Previous Installed    - None -
Version`

Comment: That's extremely old, upgrade to the latest version available for your version of PHP.

Comment: Thank you for reply. How can I update the version? I get this error `# pecl upgrade pthreads
pecl/pthreads requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0RC2), installed version is 5.4.45
No valid packages found
upgrade failed
`

Comment: Specify the version: ```pecl upgrade pthreads-2.0.10```, if you can, use PHP7, pthreads v3 is vastly superior to pthreads v2

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem.